# Call a navtab by url Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html

My Problem is the following: 
I've got three navtabs:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Personendaten</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Studienübersicht</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Dokumente</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
    <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
    <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

```js
/** A solution I found on the internet */
// Javascript to enable link to tab
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
    } 

    // Change hash for page-reload
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    })
```

Inside each menu is a post, that calls a php file that transmits some post datas from menu1 to menu2 and from menu 2 to menu 3, over the url.

My problem is and was, that when I called http://example.com/page.php#menu2 it doesn't worked. Through the JavaScript Code I found on the internet, the url shows the #menu2 when clicking on this tab.

My aim is, to call from the php file, thats called after the form of menu1 per windows.location to the new tab. 
So actually, i started like this: window.location="/html/pages/page.php#menu2?variable1='blabla';

But the windows.location only opens the page.php, not the specific tab.

I found out, that when I change the URL, press enter nothing changes.
But when I change the URL, press enter AND reload the page, it works. So, can I probably use a location.reload(); somewhere to reach my target?

I don't understand, why bootstrap doesn't get this working ... or is there any simple solution I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

This code works fine. With url.split('#'), you split your url by '#'. So if you do this:

```
window.location="/html/pages/page.php#menu2?variable1='blabla';
```

You'll have:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu2?variable1='blabla'"]').tab('show');
```

It may be why it doesn't work, you should change your url to: *page.php?variable1='blabla'#menu2*